# The procedure of debugging in java

Tags: java

What is the debugging procedure in eclipse.. i.e. how to perform a debugging on a program?

Comment: Add breakpoint to the code, and run the program in debug mode (it should be a button besides the normal "run" button). Or if you need to debug remotely, you can run the built program with jpda settings and connect to the JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) that covers basic debugging in Eclipse.

You can also use Eclipse's `Help Content` which is available through `Help` menu or can be accessed with <kbd>F1</kbd>. `Java development user guide > Tasks > Running and Debugging` contains a lot of details about debug mode and various related concepts.

[image]

These guides and others are also available at Eclipse's online [help system](http://help.eclipse.org).